# nginx not deploying at other locations

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

This is my .conf file for my nginx server deploying a flask app with gunicorn and it works perfectly on mysite.xyz  I would like the app to deploy at mysite.xyz/app  However, I must be missing something because I cannot figure it out.  I tried changing `location / {` to `location /app {` to no avail.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.xyz;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/app/app.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit location, something like that; also why u dont use fastcgi_pass

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.xyz;

location / {

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

location /app {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/app/app.sock:/app;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. :/  I'm getting `The requested URL was not found on the server.` when I go to mysite.xyz/app

Comment: nvm, it all works now, had to change my flask file to be prefaced with /app/ rather than /